# How to bring type information into value level in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, type-level-computation

I'm looking for ways of way to bring type information into value level in Haskell.

One way I know to represent any type information as a value is the `Language.Haskell.TH.Type`.
Is there any way to implement a function that takes `Proxy a` and returns `Language.Haskell.TH.Type` (or alternative type to represent any type) of the `a` type as follows?

If you have a better idea to bring type information as a value that does not use `Language.Haskell.TH.Type`, please tell me that, too.

```
import Data.Proxy (Proxy)
import Language.Haskell.TH (Type, TypeQ)

-- |
-- >>> amazing (Proxy :: Proxy Bool)
-- ConT GHC.Types.Bool
--
-- >>> amazing (Proxy :: Proxy [String])
-- AppT ListT (ConT GHC.Base.String)
amazing :: Proxy a -> Type
amazing p = undefined

-- |
-- Or if above is impossible, how about this?
amazingQ :: Proxy a -> TypeQ
amazingQ p = undefined
```

Comment: Even though I have not used it myself - but did you take a look at [Data.Data](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Data.html) maybe it provides enough information.

Comment: [`typeRep`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:typeRep) seems to be close enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It boils down to finding what you want to do with that type information. In either case, the modules you will probably be looking at are [`Data.Typeable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html) and [`Data.Data`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Data.html). At the center of these modules are the two typeclasses (deriveable via `-XDeriveDataTypeable`)

```
class Typeable a where {...}
class Typeable a => Data a where {..}
```

As @chi mentions, the former of these lets you poke a type to find out information about it. That said there is the caveat that you need instances of `Typeable` for this to work (although you can start making orphan instances of these if you really need to...). In particular, there is [`typeRep`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:typeRep):

```
ghci> import Data.Typeable
ghci> typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy (Either (Maybe [Integer]) ((), Bool, Int)))
Either (Maybe [Integer]) ((), Bool, Int)
```

However, if you ever decide you want to use the type information to try to lookup the value representations (ie. constructors) it has, you'll want to look at `Data.Data`.